# How to get result by joining two collections (tables) [Cakephp/MongoDB]

Tags: mongodb, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am using https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb.git plugin for accessing mongodb datasource.

I have two Models: Teachers and Subject. I want joint find result on  Teacher and Subject.
Here are my two models:
Teacher:

```
<?php
class Teacher extends AppModel {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasOne = array('Subject');

    public $primaryKey = '_id';
    var $mongoSchema = array(
            'name'=>array('type'=>'string'),
            'age'=>array('type'=>'string'),
            'subjectid'=>array('type'=>'string'),
            'created'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
            'modified'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
            );
```

Subject:

```
<?php
class Subject extends Model {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $belongsTo= array('Teacher');

    public $primaryKey = '_id';
    var $mongoSchema = array(
        'name'=>array('type'=>'String'),
        'code'=>array('type'=>'String'),
        'created'=>array('type'=>'datetime'),
        'modified'=>array('type'=>'datetime')
        );
```

In Teachers Controller to get joint result, I did:

```
$results = $this->Teacher->find('all',array('contain'=>array('Subject')));
$this->set('results', $results);
```

But I am not getting any result from Subjects Collections.

Here is what I am getting:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Teacher"]=>
    array(7) {
      ["_id"]=>
      string(24) "52e63d98aca7b9ca2f09d869"
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "Jon Doe"
      ["age"]=>
      string(2) "51"
      ["subjectid"]=>
      string(24) "52e63c0faca7b9272c09d869"
      ["modified"]=>
      object(MongoDate)#78 (2) {
        ["sec"]=>
        int(1390820760)
        ["usec"]=>
        int(392000)
      }
      ["created"]=>
      object(MongoDate)#79 (2) {
        ["sec"]=>
        int(1390820760)
        ["usec"]=>
        int(392000)
      }
    }
  }
```

I am a cakephp/mongoDB rookie only, Please guide me to get the desired result.

Edit: I read that mongoDb don't support Join Operation. Then How to manually do it? I mean I can write two find query on each Model, then how to combine both array and set it to view?

Comment: or I m being total dumb? I heard that mongodb don't support joins?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, MongoDB does not support joins. Documents in query results come directly from the collection being queried.

In this case, I imagine you would query for Teacher documents and then iterate over all documents and query for the Subject documents by the `subjectid` field, storing the resulting subject document in a new property on the Teacher. I'm not familiar with this CakePHP module, but you may or may not need to wrap the `subjectid` string value in a [MongoId](http://php.net/mongoid) object before querying. This depends on whether or not your document `_id` fields in MongoDB are ObjectIds or plain strings.

If Subjects only belong to a single teacher and you find that you never query for Subjects outside of the context of a Teacher, you may want to consider embedding the Subject instead of simply storing its identifier. That would remove the need to query for Subjects after the fact.